# How can I find the measure of every angle in a star polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons, angle

[image]

[image]

I'm unfamiliar with these kinds of problems.

I looked up some formulas and it says for an $(n,3)$ family of star polygons, $\theta = \frac{(1-\frac{6}{n}}{180}$

How do I get these formulas and what does $(n,3)$ family star polygon mean? how is it different from $(n,2)$ or $(n,4)$?

Answer (score 2):

What here is mentioned as $(n, 3)$ can be rewritten in Schläfli symbol notation as $\{n/3\}$, meaning drawing a regular $n$-pointed star without leaving the pen from the paper, which winds thrice around the center. The general notion then is the $\{n/d\}$.

Just as the vertex angle of a convex regular polygon can be derived to be $\varphi = 180° (1-\frac 2n)$ (by considering the according centri triangle and that the angle sum of a triangle equates to $180°$), you'd alike would derive for the star-shaped regular polygrams $\{n/d\}$ that their vertex angle quite similarily is given by $\varphi = 180° (1-\frac {2d}n)$.

--- rk

Comment: what do yo mean "winds thrice"? how can i tell how many times the graph i have winds?

Comment: it is the winding number, that is, how often you have to go around the center of symmetry until you finally return to the starting point. Eg. in order to draw a pentagram without leaving the pencil from the paper, you will have to go twice around the center of symmetry. Thus the pentagram is being denoted as $\{5/2\}$.

Comment: thank you, how can I know what the winding number is for any given polygon? Is there a formula?

Comment: well, when drawing your polygram until it closes up, then the derivation of the winding number $d$ is just counting. But you also could solve the above given formula for that number, i.e. $d=\frac n2 (1-\frac{\varphi}{180°})$. An even different way to think of it is when considering the polygram by means of a nail board (equally spaced nails in a circle) and "drawing" the polygram by means of a thread. Then $d-1$ just refers to the number of nails in circular sequence which you are omitting at each chord.